# What method to use to figure out if user is connected to facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

I am using django-social-auth for facebook login. I am able to login user using "/facebook/login". But, I need to check if user is logged in using facebook on some other page. Is there a method in the module to check if user is logged in using facebook?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the user has any facebook account as such:

```
for usersocialauth in request.user.usersocialauth_set.all():
    print usersocialauth.provider
```

You might as well get the list of providers for the user:

```
request.user.usersocialauth_set.values_list('provider')
```

Beware: a cosmic backward compatibility break was introduced in commit 7f967702. Read answer comment for detail.

Comment: In commit [7f967702](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/commit/7f9677026a420955b29294b32e969704d122f996#L6R8), a related name was added to `UserSocialAuth`. Instead of `usersocialauth_set` you must use `social_auth`.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for latest Django / python-social-auth**

This example checks if facebook is linked to the account.  Replace facebook with a valid backend name.

```
'facebook' in user.social_auth.all().values_list("provider", flat=True)
```